# How do I join integers, Decimal() and datetime.datetime() in a list?

Tags: python, pyodbc, python-datetime

I am using pyodbc to return rows from a SQL database, and I can connect and get all of the rows just fine. But now I am confused how to deal with the data returned. I would like to join all of the values in the returned list, into a string that I can then write to a file. But I am unsure how to deal with multiple data types in the list.

Here is the base code leading to the list:

```
key = "03001001"
cursor.execute('''select * from table_name where key='{}' '''.format(key))
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for x in rows:
    print(x)
```

When I `print(x)` it returns the following line:

```
('03001001', 2, datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 13, 4, 30), 0, Decimal('-0.1221'), 5, 0, 0, 0, datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 13, 14, 30), datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 13, 4, 30, 12), 0)
```

I would like for it to simply be a tab separated string.

Comment: You can turn an element into a string with the `str` function, and you can join a list of strings together with the `join` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print('\t'.join(map(repr, x)))
```

will lead to

```
'03001001'  2   datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 13, 4, 30)  0   Decimal('-0.1221')5 0   0   0   datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 13, 14, 30) datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 13, 4, 30, 12)  0
```

If you want a human readable date and decimal entry use `str` instead of `repr` (like Matti John's answer):

```
print('\t'.join(map(str, x)))
```

will print

```
03001001    2   2014-11-13 04:30:00 0   -0.1221 5   0   0   02014-11-13 14:30:00    2014-11-13 04:30:12 0
```

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, I appreciate the promptness of your response! I will give that a try!